# Why selection arguments only apply to the where clause in RawQuery?

Tags: android, sqlite

Why selection arguments only apply to the where clause in RawQuery and not, for example in the from clause?

I'm asking this because in the "from clause" you might have the same things as in the "where clause", for example when using joins.

```
SELECT table1.field_x, table2.field_y FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.field_x = table2.field_z AND table2.language =?
WHERE table1.language=?
```

I would like to make a Rawquery like this:

```
RawQuery("SELECT table1.field_x, table2.field_y FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.field_x = table2.field_z AND table2.language =?
WHERE table1.language=?",
new String[] {language, language}
```

It doesn't give a semantic error, nor a compilation error, but it's not working at execution time.

Comment: can you post the code you are using it in? your code seems fine to me

Comment: Please explain what "it's not working" means to you.

Comment: @laalto, what I mean is that the question mark in [table2.language=?] not will be replaced by one of the vars in {language, language}. It is NOT a bug, but I like to know why.

Comment: Variable binding is not string replacement. You won't see anything "replaced by one of the vars" when using selectionArgs in any way.

Answer (score -1):

> Why selection arguments only apply to the where clause in RawQuery and not

Selection arguments do not apply to rawQuery, it applies to query.

Simplest method to create rawQuery with String array parameters, as to create new StringBuffer/StringBuilder object with parameters and appending strings in SB.

For`rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '" + tableName + "'", null)`

Comment: You can use variable binding with `rawQuery()`.